# Fallout New Vegas DLC Wont activate when walking out of Doc's house

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Normally, when I walk out of Doc Mitchell's house, I usually get spammed with pop-ups regarding the DLC's radio stations, but now I get no such popups. All I get is one notification that "dead money" has been activated and my level cap increased by 5. What gives?

I've started the game before and all the radio stations popped up, but this time nothing pops up. I get every other pack, like the courier pack, and the gun runners arsenal weapons in shops, but no radio stations so I cannot start the quests. Is it a mod I'm running?

Comment: It might be, since you've decided not to mention the mods you're running. Try running the game with no mods enabled.

Comment: This should not happen. You should check the patch related to your update.

Comment: Did you checked if the mod files are really activated? The splash screen has a "Data Files" option where all loaded or unloaded mods are displayed.